# Error: “; Expected Not a statement ”

Tags: java, arrays

For the line `data[] = {nam, addres, adminStaf, phoneNumbe, typ};` NetBeans gives me this error

```
"; Expected Not a statement"
```

I don't know why this is not working, help will be appreciated.

```
public Object[] getObjects() {

           Object[] data = {};

            for (int i = 0; i < Storage.getAgencies().size(); i++)
            {
                String nam = Storage.getAgencies().get(i).getName();
                String addres = Storage.getAgencies().get(i).getAddress();
                String adminStaf = Storage.getAgencies().get(i).getAdminstaff();
                String phoneNumbe = Storage.getAgencies().get(i).getPhonenumber();
                String typ = Storage.getAgencies().get(i).getType();

                data[] = {nam, addres, adminStaf, phoneNumbe, typ};
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're using is only allowed when initializing an array. You should do the following instead:

```
data = new String[] {nam, addres, adminStaf, phoneNumbe, typ};
```

Comment: +1 but I'll note his array is a collection of Object's. Not very wise perhaps, but if that is his choice, it should be data = new Object[]{...};